# Can`t upload files to a private aws S3 bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file to aws S3 with a nodeJS server and React client app. I am new to aws so I guess I am doing something wrong. I have created a completely private backet so that only the app can access the files. The problem is that when I want to upload a file I need to get the link myBucket.getSignedUrl () in order to upload it. When I do it and send it to the frontend, the frontend fetches the link to S3 with the file I want to upload, the problem is that it returns the following error:

> Access to fetch at
> 'https://atlasworld-progress.s3.amazonaws.com/IMG_20210202_100322.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAZGHWWSFL5XOWPRXJ&Content-Type=image%2Fjpeg&Expires=1633937718&Signature=o8S8MQQ3fVdONePGOT4a5ic7CcU%3D'
> from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Here is the aws configuration file:

```js
import AWS from 'aws-sdk'

AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY
})

const S3_BUCKET ='atlasworld-progress';
const REGION =process.env.AWS_REGION;
const URL_EXPIRATION_TIME = 60; // in seconds

const myBucket = new AWS.S3({
    params: { Bucket: S3_BUCKET},
    region: REGION,
})

export const generatePreSignedPutUrl = async (fileName, fileType) => {
    const url = await myBucket.getSignedUrl('putObject', {
        Key: fileName,
        ContentType: fileType,
        Expires: URL_EXPIRATION_TIME
    });
   return url;
}
```

In the express controller it simply returns to the client the link generated by the function generatePreSignedPutUrl().
Here is the code for the frontend function in React:

```js
const [frontPhoto, setFrontPhoto] = useState();
const upload = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await JWT.checkJWT();

    const requestObject = {
        fileName: frontPhoto.name,
        fileType: frontPhoto.type,
        token: JWT.getToken()
    };

    axiosReq.post(`${serverPath}/prepare_s3`, requestObject).then((res) => {
    //the following fetch is the one that fails
      fetch(res.data, {
        method: "PUT",
        body: frontPhoto,
      }).then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      });
    });
}
```

If anyone knows what is happening I would appreciate your help.

I would also like to ask if S3 can only be uploaded one files at a time or different files can be uploaded in a single fetch.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this tells it all:

> Access to fetch from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy

you need to familiarize self with [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). If you want this to work, then you need to [enable CORS from AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/cors-troubleshooting.html).

Comment: Thanks, I configured CORS but now I get 400 (Bad Request), any idea about what can be the error?

Comment: @Gonsa02 a new error would be a candidate for a new question. based on this information I have to say no, don't have an idea

Comment: Here is the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69525166/i-cant-upload-a-file-to-aws-s3

Answer (score 0):

It's a nginx config problem, you must increase your **client_max_body_size** in nginx.conf

Steps:

1. Connect to your Beanstalk/EC2 instance via ssh:

   `ssh -i <key.pem> <ec2-user>@<host>`
2. Log in as super user:

   `$ sudo su`
3. Edit nginx.conf

   `nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`
4. Add this line inside http block

   `client_max_body_size 50M;`
5. Save file
6. Restart nginx service

   `$ service nginx restart`

**EXAMPLE NGINX CONF FILE**

```
# Elastic Beanstalk Nginx Configuration File

user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

    client_max_body_size 50M;           --------- add this line
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    log_format  healthd '$msec"$uri"$status"$request_time"$upstream_response_time"$http_x_forwarded_for';

    include       /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include       /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Comment: I'm not using EC2, it's only a React and NodeJS app but I need to use S3 for storage of photos.

Comment: Your nodejs app are running on localhost? 

@Gonsa02