# I can`t upload a file to AWS S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload files to AWS S3 using getSignedUrlPromise () to obtain the access link since the bucket is completely private, I want it to only be accessible through the links that the server generates with getSignedUrlPromise ().

The problem comes when I try to make a put to that link obtained since I get the following error, I also leave you the response that I receive.

[image]

> Response {type: 'cors', url: 'https://atlasfitness-progress.s3.amazonaws.com/IMG…a9a56b532bdfe1a139d5a451&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host', redirected: false, status: 400, ok: false, …}body: ReadableStreamlocked: false[[Prototype]]: ReadableStreambodyUsed: falseheaders: Headers {}ok: falseredirected: falsestatus: 400statusText: "Bad Request"type: "cors"url: "https://atlasfitness-progress.s3.amazonaws.com/IMG_20210202_100322.jpg?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAZGHWWSFL5XOWPRXJ%2F20211011%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20211011T181242Z&X-Amz-Expires=60&X-Amz-Signature=88461e762045c9e34e22c7d011ca7b7649700c9da9a56b532bdfe1a139d5a451&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host"[[Prototype]]: Response

Here is the code for configuring aws in nodeJS:

```js
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

const bucketName = 'atlasfitness-progress';
const region =process.env.AWS_REGION;
const accessKeyId = process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY
const secretAccessKey = process.env.AWS_SECRET_KEY

const URL_EXPIRATION_TIME = 60; // in seconds

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    region,
    accessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey,
    signatureVersion: 'v4'
})

export const generatePreSignedPutUrl = async (fileName, fileType) => {

    const params = ({
        Bucket: bucketName,
        Key: fileName,
        Expires: 60
    })

    const url = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise('putObject', params);

   return url;
}
```

And then I have a express controller to send the link when it's requested:

```js
routerProgress.post('/prepare_s3', verifyJWT, async (req, res) => {
  res.send({url: await generatePreSignedPutUrl(req.body.fileName, req.body.fileType)});
})

export { routerProgress };
```

But the problem comes in the frontend, here is the function that first asks for the link and then it tryies to upload the file to S3.

```js
const upload = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await JWT.checkJWT();

    const requestObject = {
        fileName: frontPhoto.name,
        fileType: frontPhoto.type,
        token: JWT.getToken()
    };

    const url = (await axiosReq.post(`${serverPath}/prepare_s3`, requestObject)).data.url;
    //Following function is the one that doesn't work
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
      },
      body: frontPhoto
  });
    console.log(response);
}
```

And with this all is done, I can say that I am a newbie to AWS so it is quite possible that I have caused a rather serious error without realizing it. So if anyone detects the error or knows how I can make it work I would be very grateful for your help.

Comment: Can you please paste the raw output of `console.log(response);`?

Comment: Yes I have edited the post to paste it in. Please if you know what's wrong let me know, I have lost lots of time with that.

Comment: We'll figure it out! Are you calling this from `localhost`?

Comment: Yes I'm calling it on an app in react running in localhost

Comment: It seems you have a CORS issue - go to **Buckets** > **Permissions** > **Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)** > **Edit** > Add this into there: `[{"AllowedHeaders":["*"],"AllowedMethods":["*"],"AllowedOrigins":["*"],"ExposeHeaders":[]}]` > **Save Changes** - try again, does that work?

Comment: I get the following error in aws page when I have tried to save it. Found unsupported HTTP method in CORS config. Unsupported method is *

Comment: Change `"*"` to `"PUT"`, apologies forgot that it doesn't take a wildcard value

Comment: okay I'll try but my old configuration was similar to the one you are sending. ```[{"AllowedHeaders": ["*"], "AllowedMethods": ["PUT","POST","DELETE"], "AllowedOrigins": ["*"],"ExposeHeaders": [],"MaxAgeSeconds": 3000}]```

Comment: Error persist :(

Comment: Hm..  for now, add the JSON object for the response to the question please as well as reset your previous CORS config & also add that to the question - comments can get lost etc.

Comment: We can't see the contents of `response.Body` - we need the full object, `console.log` it in your application please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238035/discussion-between-gonsa02-and-ermiya-eskandary).